# How to obtain logs in locomotiveJS?

Tags: javascript, locomotivejs

I am new to the locomotiveJS framework. I want to test my code and log some data. What is the proper way of loggin info in locomotiveJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `console.log()` in your code, it will appear on the console.

If you want to log data to a file, Locomotive doesn't have any solutions for that itself. But you can use any of the available log packages, like [`log`](https://npmjs.org/package/log), for that:

```
// config/initializers/10_log.js
var fs  = require('fs');
var Log = require('log');

module.exports = function() {
  this.logger = new Log('debug', fs.createWriteStream('my.log'));
};

// in your controller
MyController.main = function() {
  this.app.logger.info('HELLO WORLD');
  ...
};
```

Explanation: 'initializers' are files that are executed by Locomotive when it starts up. This particular initializer configures the `log` package to write to a file `my.log` in the directory where you start your server. It will attach the logger object to the Locomotive application object.

In your controller methods, you can access that logger object as `this.app.logger`.